# Handling 'no such comm' errors in VSCode Jupyter Notebook when using widgets

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am experiencing a recurring issue with 'no such comm' errors in Visual Studio Code when working with Jupyter Notebooks that utilize widgets. Although the cells containing the widgets execute without problems, the subsequent cells consistently throw a 'no such comm' error. This forces me to re-execute the problematic cell and all cells below it, rather than allowing me to run the entire notebook smoothly.

Here's what I've attempted so far to resolve the issue:

- I have reinstalled my conda environment from scratch.
- I have updated all the relevant packages to ensure they are the latest versions.
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled VSCode entirely.\

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. The error doesn't seem to prevent the widgets from functioning, but it disrupts the flow of working through the notebook.
Here are some additional details that might be relevant:

- VSCode version:
  Version: 1.87.2 (user setup)
  Commit: 863d2581ecda6849923a2118d93a088b0745d9d6
  Date: 2024-03-08T15:20:17.278Z
  Electron: 27.3.2
  ElectronBuildId: 26836302
  Chromium: 118.0.5993.159
  Node.js: 18.17.1
  V8: 11.8.172.18-electron.0
  OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
- Jupyter extension version: v2024.2.0
- Operating System:
  OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 11 Enterprise
  OS Version:                10.0.22631 N/A Build 22631
  OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
  OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation

Has anyone else encountered this, and are there known solutions or workarounds that I might not have tried? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a snippet of the issue
[image]

Also when I check the output of jupyter notebook at the error I get the following message:

```
[error] Failed to handle iopub message as a result of some comm message
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: "I have updated all the relevant packages to ensure they are the latest versions." What packages? What widgets? You may not realize this but widgets is a general term. Are you using [anywidget](https://github.com/manzt/anywidget)? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), pay special attention to the section 'Help others reproduce the problem'. It emphasizes sharing a minimal reproducible example and not sharing only screenshots. You can supplement with a screenshot for situations where you are trying to show behavior but you need to share code as text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)